# SQL Azure: New User Can't Log In

Tags: sql, database, azure

I am attempting to create a new user in SQL azure and I have used the following method in SSMS:

On Master:

```
CREATE LOGIN TestConnectionLgn WITH password='xxxxxxxx';
GO
CREATE USER TestConnectionUsr FROM LOGIN TestConnectionLgn;
GO
```

On DB:

```
CREATE USER TestConnectionUsr FROM LOGIN TestConnectionLgn;
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'TestConnectionUsr';
GO
```

I can see the user on the database:

```
UserName            RoleName    LoginName           DefDBName  DefSchemaName
TestConnectionUsr   db_owner    TestConnectionLgn   master     dbo
```

But When I test my connection from a UDL file or from Management Studio I get a login failed error (even if I use the login instead of the user)).  It's not the firewall because I can log in using the sa credentials, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you paste the exact error as text

Comment: From the UDL: Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider

Comment: Pls share Error in ssms as well

Comment: From SSMS: Cannot Connect to [DB] Login failed for user

Comment: please paste entire along with codes,state etc..

Comment: TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to [DB]

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'TestConnectionLgn'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Comment: it seems the password is wrong and softwares are 100% correct in this scenarios

Comment: I'm afraid not, I've copied and pasted the password

Answer (score 0):

When you connect from SSMS, do you click the options button and change the Connect to database: to target the database the user has access to in Azure? You can't use the default option here when connecting to SQL Azure.

Comment: Yes I've made sure to select the correct DB in options

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to create my user based on [this article](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/04/08/azure-sql-pro-tip-creating-login-account-and-user/). I think that the main fix was to select the databases in SSMS, right click and select 'New Query' instead of changing the DB in the dropdown in the toolbar (I don't know why this is although I suspect it's something to do with the time it was taking to communicate the change in database on the remote DB server).

For those that come after me here is the full procedure:

In Object Explorer right click the **master DB** and select **new query**

In  the query window write and execute the following statement:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'[MYNEWLOGIN])
 CREATE LOGIN [MYNEWLOGIN] WITH PASSWORD=N'[MYNEWPASSWORD]'
GO
```

In Object Explorer **right click** the database you want to add the new user to select **new query**

In  the query window write and execute the following statement:

```
CREATE USER [MYNEWLOGIN] FOR LOGIN [MYNEWLOGIN] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [MYNEWLOGIN]
GO
```

That should be it